# How to write a function that uses sqlite to connect to the database and query data in lisp

Tags: sqlite, common-lisp, clsql

I have written this function:

```
(defun load-db (filename)
  (with-open-file (in filename)
    (with-standard-io-syntax
      (setf *db* (read in)))))
```

I have a database in local called `xx.db`, I want to use sqlite to connect it and something I can query like this:

```
(defvar *db* (connect "~/xx.db"))
(execute-single *db* "select ss_type from capitalization where lemma = ?" "A")
```

How can I do it?
It won't run for the above query, and I also already include SQLite package, and give the path to the xx.db

Comment: Please read this article, before asking a question [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

What database library did you try ?

With [clsql](http://clsql.kpe.io/manual/), you can do something like:

```
(ql:quickload "clsql")
(clsql:connect "xx" :database-type :sqlite)
(clsql:execute-command "from ...")
```

Other DB libraries: https://github.com/CodyReichert/awesome-cl#database

Comment: I used wordnet, but I have wordnet.db file in my local. Do I need open the file or open the database, how I can insert my query?

Comment: Word net is a series of files that would need to be imported into sql. There appear to be a number of github projects That deal with wordnet, this one github.com/TheDarkTrumpet/cl-wordnet claims to be a cl interface to an sql wordnet.. if you ask a question again please provide more context so we understand what you are asking

Comment: I have wordnet database files which stored in wordnet.db in different directory, I want to write functions that can connect my database wordnet.db in cl sqlite, then query two tables. I am trying to write functions in aquamacs.

Comment: I think the first thing is to make sure that wordnet.db is indeed an sqlite database - you can use http://sqlitebrowser.org/ to make sure that it is indeed a sqllite db and that sqlite is properly installed. If it works, then clsql is a very easy way to connect to it from lisp.